Modifying a file, Merging the branch without deleting branch, then reverting that file to it's original state
I have two branches I call production and testing_branch. During the month, merge requests are made to test, end of month we test the testing_branch, and if all good merge into production.
I want to disable a feature that isn't working in the testing_branch, merge it into production, then reenable it on the testing_branch so I can keep working on it. This means I will be modifying some lines of code, deleting some files etc.
We can't directly push to either branch, so currently my plan is to :

Save copies locally of the files I need to change/delete
Create a copy of testing_branch, make the changes and merge copy to testing_branch
Test and merge testing_branch to production
Make another copy of testing_branch and copy back the local copies from step 1
Merge this copy back to testing_branch

I was wondering if there was a neater way of doing this in git?

Consider looking at stashing the changes?

That is much neater than saving the files locally manually, thank you.

If the feature to disable has been commited and merged in testing_branch through PR, stashing won't help. @Ciaran How many commits are there for this feature (not counting merge commits)?

Revert the change on testing_branch. Merge it into production. Unrevert on testing_branch.

These convoluted problems keep showing up with these “testing and then production” branches “workflows”.  I am yet to see any benefit being realized from them.

So you have some non-permanent (aka temporary) changes you want to apply to your testing_branch and have available locally that you do not want to push to the remote branch. This is exactly the scenario I describe with temporary commits. One additional note is that that answer mentions deleting the temporary commits before pushing, but you do not need to drop them completely, "moving" them to a different branch (say testing_branch_local) is perfectly fine.
